# Sylow p-subgroups of a finite group G which are contained in some other subgroup H are also Sylow p-subgroups in H

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have found a proof to the following question but I don't quite understand it.

Let $P \leq H \leq G$ and $|G|=p^\alpha m$, where $p$ doesn't divide $m$.

I need to show that if $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

*Proof:*

$p  $ does not divide $[G : P]=[G : H][H : P]$ so p also does not divide $[H : P]$

Since p does not divide $[H : P]$, P is a Sylow p-subgroup of H. This is the line that I don't understand.

Comment: Review the definition of a Sylow $p$-subgroup!

Comment: So, since H is a group of order $p^\alpha k$ and P is a subgroup of H and $|P|=p^\alpha$. By definition, P is a Sylow p-subgroup of H. Doesn't this make the first line of the proof irrelevant?

Comment: Yes it's an extremely trivial result!